# why do i get this TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Tags: python, typeerror

First I just want to set the target_x and target_y, actually reading_x and reading_y refers to an accelerometer but to make the code simpler i set the values to 400

```
reading_x = 400
if  reading_x > 300:
    target_x = 4 
elif 100 < reading_x < 300:
    target_x = 3
elif -100 > reading_x >-300:
    target_x = 1 
elif reading_x < -300:
    target_x = 0
else:
    target_x =2
reading_y = 400
if  reading_y > 300:
    target_y = 4 
elif 100 < reading_y < 300:
    target_y = 3
elif -100 > reading_y >-300:
    target_y = 1 
elif reading_y < -300:
    target_y = 0
else:
    target_y =2
print(target_x, target_y)


# 4, 4
```

it's a game and I just set positions of different car in a 5x5 board game and create a dictionary to save their positions

```
nb_car = 4
car_life = 2
car_dict = {}

while len (car_dict) < nb_sm:
    for car in range (nb_sm):
        car_x = randint(0,4)
        car_y = randint(0,4)
        car_dict[car +1] = {'x':car_x, 'y':car_y, 'life': car_life }
print(car_dict)


#{1: {'life': 2, 'x': 4, 'y': 4}, 2: {'life': 2, 'x': 4, 'y': 4}, 3: {'life': 2, 'x': 4, 'y': 4}, 4: {'life': 2, 'x': 4, 'y': 4}}
```

in the game i want to destroy a car so i want to check if the target_x and target_y (4,4) will destroy a car but when i write this i get the TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

```
target_x in sm_dict[1]['x']
```

can someone please help me ?

Comment: what the variable nb_sm means in your code?

Comment: `in` operator expects an iterable object on the right side  but you are providing an integer, therefore error occurred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in` operator expects an iterable object on the right side  but you are providing an integer, therefore error occurred

Either use

```
if target_x == sm_dict[1]['x']:
    #Do your stuff
```

Or

```
car_data in sm_dict:
    if sm_dict[car_data]['x'] == target_x:
        #Do your stuff
```